# Get data using hibernate criterian with list of values

Tags: java, hibernate

I have classes like this

--status class--

```
public class Status  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>(0);
}
```

--item class--

```
public class Item  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer itemId;
     private Set<Status> statuses = new HashSet<Status>(0);
}
```

Now i need to get all the items which are having status `OK`

I have done something like this but it is not working

```
Status status = new Status();
Set<Status> stset = new HashSet<Status>();
stset.add(status)
List<Criterion> criterionList = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
criterionList.add(Restrictions.in("statuses", stset));
```

Comment: How did you represent Status OK..? is it name = 'OK' or id = 1

Comment: @ManuPK using the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How try like this,

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
criteria.createAlias("statuses", "statuses");   
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("statuses.name", "OK"));
List<Item> items = criteria.list();
```

Comment: thanks it works and one more question can i add more `createAlias` to different tables

Comment: You can use `createAlias` for relationship. E.g `criteria.createAlias("a.b.name", "bName");` Here is [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations)